# error: redefinition of 'struct tm'

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

When including both `<string>` and `<chrono>` with MinGW 32, I recieve the error
`error: redefinition of 'struct tm'` during compilation (G++) from the files `wchar.h` and `time.h`.

Sidenote: it also occurs with `<iostream>` and `<sstream>` along with `<chrono>`

I first observed this after adding `chrono`, and it seems it is the source of the conflicts.

Thanks in advance.

Exact code:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ game.cpp base.cpp -IC:\Users\julian\Documents\SDL2\include\SDL2 -LC:\Users\julian\Documents\SDL2\lib -w -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image  -o game
```

Comment: So do both your input files contain the code you posted or is one of them empty?

Comment: You can preprocess the guilty .cpp by adding `-E` to the command line, and then inspect the preprocess to find the source of the redefinition.

Comment: Obviously a toolchain bug so raise it with the MinGW maintainers.

Comment: @Galik I experience the same bug in the other file, but in this example, I have commented those lines in the second file.